# Is there's any way to have mqtt connection with background service?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native android and want to ask if there's any way to have mqtt connection with background service so that when the app closes I can still receive messages via mqtt?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself, but this should be somewhat possible.  While I do not know if it is possible to leave a single connection open that will receive MQTT messages regardless if the app is running in the foreground, running in the background, or has run and closed, I do think that effect can be achieved.

Background tasks (run when the app is in the background or has been closed) do not always work cross-platform (mostly Android-only), and do not allow you to run on an event-based trigger like receiving an MQTT publish.  For this reason, you will see my suggestions based on things like `setInterval` and checking for messages at a given point.  Because the connection is not alive at all times, you will have to either set a large keep-alive interval (or unclean sessions) on the MQTT connection to match with the interval you are checking for messages and rely on QoS 1 or 2 (harder), or close and re-open MQTT connections and rely on retain (easier).

If you only need the MQTT messages to get through when the application is in the foreground or background, you can use something like https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer to `setInterval` and wake-up to check for messages at specific intervals that have tight granularity.  If you need the messages to get through even when the app has been closed, you require something like https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job , which will only allow you to run code at a granularity of 15 minutes and above.

I wish you the best of luck!